# error happened when link a shared library in CMake

Tags: c, cmake

I am studying CMake. I make a simple testing listed below:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(MAIN) 
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include) 
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_LIB}/lib) 
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main hello)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.c)
```

That's code of CMakeLists.txt. I run it but report a error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES): 
Cannot specify link libraries for target "main" which is not built by this 
project
```

main.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "hello.h"

int main() 
{ 
  HelloFunc(); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried inverting the order of the last two lines?

Comment: @Mat is right : `add_executable()` will define `main` as a target for current project, and the target `main` will be defined as `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES()` is called.

Comment: you are right. I have build success after do that. Thanks!